# Android / XML : Referring to a element which is declared later

Tags: android, xml

eclipse shows me an error when I'm referring to a element that is declared later. How can I solve this or is there any kind of work around. Here is the part of my xml-layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:padding="5dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView1"   <!-- error -->
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView1"      <!-- error -->
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1"
        android:src="@drawable/folder" />
```

I want the ImageView to be to the right of the checkbox, but I also want the checkBox to be as "high" as the ImageView (the checkbox should be still a square)

regards

Comment: you can not take reference of later added object in relative layout

Comment: You declare `ImageView` with id **imageView1** _AFTER_ `CheckBox` with id **checkBox1**. Just swap the ordering around - i.e. `ImageView` should be declared **BEFORE** `CheckBox` - and you're good to go!

Comment: the problem is that ImageView1 also refers to checkBox1. So it's still the same problem

Comment: Please avoid **circular references**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap the CheckBox and the ImageView and remove `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"` from the ImageView (in order to avoid a `circular reference`):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/folder"
/>
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
/>
```

Otherwise, the CheckBox can't refer the ImageView's id, since it hasn't been created yet

**[EDIT]**

An even better way to do that is incorporating the ImageView into the CheckBox, as a compound drawable:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/folder"
    android:layout_drawablePadding="10dp"
/>
```

Note that now the image is on the right side of the checkbox.
This is a **best practice**.

Comment: But then imageView1 would not be to the right of the checkbox right?

Comment: No, it won't be. See my edited answer for a solution that better matches your case. And it's a best practice too

Comment: But then I wouldn't need imageView1 as the image is already shown in checkBox1. Is there a way to make the checkBox drawable (the square) as high as the drawable on the right side?

Comment: Of course, if you put the image into the CheckBox, you don't have to provide another ImageView. In my edited answer, I forgot to remove the ImageView references from the CheckBox, sorry - now it's fixed

Comment: Is there a way to set the height of the checkBox-square (the actual drawable) at all?

Comment: Do you need a custom CheckBox, then?

Comment: Something like this (you may replace the xml drawables with images): http://androidexample.com/Custom_Checkbox_With_The_Use_Of_Selectors_And_Shapes/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=80&aaid=104

Answer (score 3):

@kalyan pvs....it is ok but you should not call each time with "@+id" which means you are creating new instance each time. This is wrong way of referring to an item in relative layout. In this, rendering errors will come when you are referring to a view which will be created after the present view. The right way of calling reference is @id only.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a `View` later is not a problem, Try this, Reduced some lines of your code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but how can I make the checkBox as high as the imageView then?

Comment: Please elaborate about your requirement, High means?

Comment: both views should have the same height

Comment: You need to set the height and width of Checkbox same as that of your image named 'folder'. Or use another image with same dimensions as background for checkbox.

Comment: In px units? But the dimensions of 'folder' will be different for the different screen-resoultion categories (drawable-hdpi,...)

Comment: The foolproof solution is to have alike image as 'folder' and place in your different drawable folders. If you do not want to use different image just check hardcode the dimesions of medium sized image(drawable-mdpi) in 'dp' only. The OS will automatically adjust it for rest of the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:padding="5dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"   
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"     
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:src="@drawable/folder" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```